# Which one is more efficient ToListAsync() or ToList()

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm using.NET 6 core API to get data from a database. I'm not sure whether to use **ToListAsync()** or **ToList()**, and which is more efficient.

While saving the data in db also, I am not sure whether to use **SaveChangesAsync()** or **SaveChanges()**

**Get the data using ToListAsync()**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("[action]")]
public async Task <IActionResult> GetDataAsync() {

  var result = await _context.Employee.ToListAsync();
  return Ok(result);
}
```

**Get the data using ToList()**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("[action]")]
public IActionResult GetDataAsync() {

  var result = _context.Employee.ToList();
  return Ok(result);
}
```

Kindly provide an suggestion

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30042791/entity-framework-savechanges-vs-savechangesasync-and-find-vs-findasync and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52588644/entity-framework-core-tolist-vs-tolistasync

Comment: It actually depends. For ASP applications use the `async` versions.

Comment: What do you mean `efficient` in the first place? Neither affects the generated SQL. Loading an entire table into memory is always slower than loading only what's really necessary.

Comment: The actual difference is whether the calling thread blocks while waiting for the query to execute. `ToList()` blocks the calling thread while `ToListAsync()` doesn't. In web applications, all requests are server from threads that come from a threadpool so avoiding blocking is good. Creating threads is expensive in all OSs so high-traffic web servers always try to reuse threads. Loading an entire table in memory though is very bad.

Comment: If you really need to return the entire table, use `AsEnumerable()` or `AsAsyncEnumerable()`. Right now you're caching the entire table in memory twice. Once in the `result` list and once in ASP.NET Core's output buffer. By using either `AsEnumerable()` or `AsAsyncEnumerable()` the code won't have to load everything in memory before ASP.NET Core starts sending the output to the client